# CSS: Text-Shadow buggy?

Tags: css

I'm having an issue with web programming when I combine text-shadow with text-stroke.
The shadow version of the same text gets cut on the sides, and that's not what I would expect it to do.
Does anyone know how to avoid this issue while still using both shadow and stroke at those rates?

I can actually see that out of Safari it doen't show the same effects.
Does anyone know of a good replacement of the stroke?

Here's the code of what I'm using.

```css
p {
  margin: 80px;
  color: green;
  text-shadow: 90px 0px red;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 10px;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<p>V</p>
<p>O</p>
```

Comment: I was under the impression that `text-stroke` had been abandoned...for the time being....it's definitely got **very** poor support. Not to be used in production.

Comment: Agreed, it only works in chrome and safari

Comment: I can actually see that you were right.
Out of Safari, it doen't show the same effects.

Comment: It's there any good replacement of that code to achieve the same effect??

Answer (score 0):

Just keep on adding to this logic. Not sure if there is a max. Sorry about giving up on you earlier.

```
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #000, 2px 2px 0 #000, 3px 3px 0 #000, 4px 4px 0 #000;
```

Comment: Hi, the issue is that the the shadow, when it shows the stroke on the shadow, the shadow is cut on the sides.
If you have safari, you can try this rule, it will show you what I mean(it apparently works on safary, doesn't show the stroke on other browsers):

    p{
 margin: 80px;
 color: green;
 text-shadow: 200px 1px 0 #000;
 -webkit-text-stroke: 50px blue;
 -o-text-stroke: 50px blue;
 -moz-text-stroke: 50px blue;
 font-size: 9em;
    }